# Unbable to sort the columns

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables.

```
searchResultsTable = $("#searchResultsTable").dataTable({
    "bServerSide": true,
    "sAjaxSource": "searchResults.form",
    "bProcessing": false,       
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {"sEmptyTable": "No data available", "sLengthMenu" :" _MENU_ items per page",
    "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
    "sInfoEmpty": "No entries to show"},
    "sDom": 'tlip',
    "aaSorting": [],
    "aoColumns": [null,null,null,null,{ "bVisible": false }]
});
```

I have provided the `aaSorting`, so that the data gets sorted when user clicks on the header. But it's not working. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **CAUSE**

You have server-side processing mode enabled with `"bServerSide": true`. In this mode, data processing including sorting, filtering and ordering should be performed on the server and the returned data need to have [certain structure](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data). See [Processing modes](http://datatables.net/manual/data#Processing-modes) for more information.

> **SOLUTION**

If you are not performing data processing on the server, simply remove `"bServerSide": true` and DataTables will perform sorting, filtering and ordering on the client-side.

Comment: Thanks. I handled the sorting on the server side. :)