# Search is not working in server side processing mode

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

I use jQuery DataTables (http://datatables.net/) to load some data from Database and represent in a view, I used ASP MVC 5 and MSSQL 2008. when i comment   "bServerSide": true, part the searching is working perfectly but once it true, everything i type a letter in search box, it goes to my GET Method which is don't want.

I want to search data from previews loaded, can anyone help bellow is my code,

```
    var salaryMonth = $('#emid').val();
    var a = $('#emid').val();
    var b = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "/EventLog/GetData",
        "fnServerParams": function (aoData) {
            aoData.push({ "name": "salaryMonth", "value": a });
            aoData.push({ "name": "salaryDay", "value": b });
        },
        "bServerSide": true,
        "fnDrawCallback": function () {

        },
        "fnServerData": function (sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {

            $.ajax({
                "type": "GET",
                "dataType": 'json',
                "contentType": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                "url": sSource,
                "data": aoData,
                "success": function (data) {
                    fnCallback(data);

                }
            });
        },
        "aoColumns": [
            { "sTitle": "DateTime", "mData": "LogDate", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "user", "mData": "sUserName", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "user Name", "mData": "nUserID", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "Device", "mData": "nReaderIdn", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "Device Name", "mData": "ReaderName", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "Event", "mData": "nEventIdn", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "Event name", "mData": "EventDate", "bSortable": true },
            { "sTitle": "T&A event", "mData": "nTNAEvent", "bSortable": true },

    ]
    });
```

Comment: why don't you cache the results and serve them from there on the next call?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unbable to sort the columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32201482/unbable-to-sort-the-columns)

Comment: Stefan, but when i set bServerSide to false it works without chasing, can i do the same thing with bServerSide, true?

Comment: Do you just want to do a client-side search on the data you've loaded from the server?

Comment: Server side data but once data loaded then client side filtering